# How are rivnuts measured and what eyebolt fits?

Tags: fence, construction, steel

At Amazon, I've seen `RN14 1/4"-20 steel rivet nuts`, `RN516 5/16"-18 steel rivet nuts`, `RN1024 #10-24 steel rivet nuts`, `1/4-20UNC`, `3/8-16`, `M3`, `M5`, etc.

I also saw the following image explaining the size of a 1/4" rivnut, but it doesn't make sense to me.

So my question is: how *wide* and how *long* is an 1/4"-20 rivnut and what drill bit do I need to make the hole so it fits correctly? And what size eyebolt would fit this rivnut?

I'm buying the rivnuts and the eyebolts online, so I would need to be sure of the sizes.

Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Each brand of rivnuts have there dimensions required for the hole. Depending on the brand there can be several different hole sizes. My suggestion would be to drill the smallest hole possible and press the nut in this way it will hold better.

Comment: Took to long to edit after hitting enter by accident, the nuts you posted are 1/4" with 20 threads per inch or 1/4-20 so that would be the size of eye bolt needed.

Comment: The photo you posted shows the width, OD (outer diameter), of the rivnut 8.8mm/.035". That is just bigger than 5/16 but just smaller than 3/8. i would try a test with a 5/16" drill bit. If you buy some that do not have the OD listed and you do not have calipers then just hold it up to a some drill bits and start with one that looks just smaller, do some tests.

Answer (score 3):

They are typically listed by the size of bolt that will fit in them.  For example. `RN14 1/4"-20 steel rivet nuts`, would accept a 1/4" bolt that has 20 threads per inch.

If you look at the details of the "rivnut" (either in the details provided on the website, or by looking them up through the manufacturer), you should be able to find some other useful dimensions.  "*Hole Size*" should be listed somewhere in the details, which is the size of the hole that has to be drilled for the rivnut to fit into.  You should also find "*Grip Range*", which is the range of material thicknesses that the rivnut can be used in. You should also find the "*Head Diameter*", and the "*Length*" of the rivnut.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The size quoted is the size of the bolt that would be used with it (the same as a normal nut - so an M8 rivnut would be used with an M8 (8mm metric) bolt.

In the example in your picture, a 1/4"-20 rivnut would need a 1/4"-20 UNC bolt (1/4" diameter, 20 teeth per inch), and would need an 8.8mm/0.375" hole (most likely, 9mm or 3/8")

Comment: Thanks. What screw would fit this 1/4" rivnut?

Comment: Any bolt or setscrew with a 1/4"-20 UNC thread should fit

Comment: 1/4"BSW (British Standard Witworth) will also fit it is also 20 TPI ( Threads Per Inch)